# hide/show columns $row depending checkbox or radio

Tags: javascript, checkbox, row, hide, show

I need to create a checkbox that hide the rows that contain MULTIPLE in CARS value from a CRUD.
This is the part where I need to implement the checkbox:

```html
     <body>
 <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ;  ?>
      
      <form name="form">                        
        Hiden Multiple: <input type="checkbox" id="ck"
 ***onclick="hide if $row['Cars']= Multiple, if not show :D "***/>
      </form>


        <table id="tabla" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
               
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['Years']; ?></td>
                
            </tr>
   <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['Cars']; ?></td>
               
            </tr>
        </table>   
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can point you in the direction, but you need to code it yourself.

- PHP / HTML: you need one form, so place your  outside your while-loop
- PHP / HTML: add an css class to the table when condition "$row['Cars'] == 'Multiple'" is true eq:
- Javascript: hide / show elements with class "has_multiple_cars" when checking/unchecking the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only found this java and work but with de number of the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function ocultarFila(numFila) {                
                var form = document.form;
                fila = document.getElementById('tabla').getElementsByTagName('tr')[numFila];
                if(form.ck.checked == true) {      
                    fila.style.display = 'none';
                } else {                   
                    fila.style.display = '';
                }          
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ;  
?>
        <form name="form">
            Hiden Multiple: <input type="checkbox" id="ck" onclick="ocultarFila(1)"/>
        </form>
```

Can make a condition for me? I'm starting to program and I do not find the right sentence, thanks!